# How to change stroke color in pygal?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygal

How to set one to red and second to blue?

```
import pygal

chart = pygal.Line()

chart.x_labels = range(5)
chart.add('one', [1, None, 3, None, 5])
chart.add('two', range(5))

chart.render_to_png(__file__ + '-linear.png')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pygal's [Custom Styles](http://www.pygal.org/en/latest/documentation/custom_styles.html) to define specific colors for the series that you are loading. The only drawback is that the colors are assigned based on series order, so in your case you should set the colors parameter to `('red','blue')` so that they match your serie order.

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom styles as follows.

```
from pygal.style import Style

yourCustomStyle = Style(
    ...
    colors=['#hex_color1', '#hex_color2', ...],
    ...
)

yourChart = pygal.Line(style=yourCustomStyle)
yourChart.add('Series1', [value1, value2, value3, ...])
yourChart.add('Series2', [value1, value2, value3, ...])
...
yourChart.render()
```

You have many styling options to change colors, font-size, font-family, background, transparency etc...
Check official [documentation here](http://pygal.org/en/stable/documentation/custom_styles.html)

By the time I'm posting this, there is a mistake in the doc though. They have provided tuple of colors rather that a list, for `colors` option in their example. You have to use a `list[]` for adding colors in your custom styles.